# Running App on ios7

Tags: xcode, ios7

I have a question regarding "Running my application on ios7" but i don't have xcode version for ios7 because i am getting confuse which xcode version is suitable for it.And also which MacOS is required for it.

I have read somewhere that it requires Xcode5 so i installed it but when i tried to open xcode5 it gaves an alert that "You need to update your Mac OS version  to 10.8.4".
So i tried for it on software updation but after 5 minutes it gives an alert that "Your Mac Os is already updated" and mine current OS is 10.7.5.

So please tell me how do i do i run my app on iOS7 ?

Comment: Be aware that iOS7 is still under NDA and there for you are not allowed to talk about it, other then on the official Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: You need XCode 5 to run iOS 7. And to install XCode 5 you need OS 10.8.4 onwards.

Comment: @rckoenes: so sir is itn't possible to get our app runnable on ios 7??Please tell me it's urgent for me right now.

Comment: iOS 7 is not released yet, you can test your app for now. But Apple might change things before the final release. See my answer to solve you install issue. Even when iOS 7 is released you will need OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

Comment: @Rushi: Is installing OS 10.8.4 from http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1659 is correct and won't need any charges??

Comment: @rckoenes:Ok Thanxs but if my app which is runnable on iOS 6 is even not launching on the iphone with ios 7.do you know the reason of it??

Comment: @iOSDeveloper you will need to test it with the iOS 7 SDK, but just to let you know there might be something there that Apple will fix before release. Since you can not yet submit Apps build with the iOS 7 SDK you might not be able to fix that at the current time. Apple will release the Release candidates soon which will allow for better testing and when the GM is out you will be able to submit app to the AppStore.

Comment: @Rushi the link you gave will only work if you have Mountain Lion and not Lion.

Comment: @Rushi :Please tell me if my friend have mountain Lion But i have Lion Version then how do i get it from him??i can insatll it but it takes lot of time.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper You are suggesting that you install his version of Mountain Lion? That is against the license and there for illegal. Also the install will take just as long.

Answer (score 5):

Buy OSX Mountain Lion from the Appstore and upgrade.

Comment: Is this really the only way (now that iOS 7 has been released)? Can I not deploy to iOS 7 from the highest version of Xcode that runs on OSX Lion?

Comment: No the iOS 7 SDK is only available with Xcode 5 which need  OS X 10.8.4 or higher.